# Using Slick-Carousel and NPM

Tags: jquery-plugins, npm, webpack

Still trying to master NPM and hit some roadblocks.

My slick-carousel works great when I use the CDN process. But I'm doing everything in NPM so figured I should do the same with this plug-in, but can't seem to get it off the ground.

Ran the install:

```js
npm install slick-carousel --save
```

Which adds to my package.json file:

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.11.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "img-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0"
  }
```

I'm smart enough to know that I need to require the file in my index.js file:

```js
var $ = require('jquery');

require("../css/style.css");
require("font-awesome-webpack");
require("slick-carousel");
```

I can see that I now have all the jQuery for slick-carousel, but none of the css.

Now I figure I should require the two .css files living in the node_modules folder:

```js
require("slick-carousel/slick/slick.css");
require("slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css");
```

And this is where it all breaks.  The slick.css file loads and the basic slick-carousel is now working in my html output. But the slick-theme file breaks everything by pushing this error:

```js
./~/slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif
Module parse failed: /Users/ryanbuchholtz/Documents/thinkful/haventower/node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif Unexpected character '' (1:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '' (1:7)
```

This makes me think something is broken in my webpack.config.js:

```js
var path = require('path');
var packageData = require('./package.json');
var filename = [packageData.name, packageData.version, 'js'];

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');



var plugins = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: 'head',
      template: 'index.html',
      minify: {
        "collapseWhitespace": true, 
        "removeComments": true, 
        "removeRedundantAttributes": true, 
        "removeScriptTypeAttributes": true, 
        "removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes": true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ];

module.exports = {
    entry: {
      main: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, packageData.main)
      ]
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: filename.join('.'),
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: plugins,
    module: {
      loaders: [
        { 
          test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader", "file-loader")
        },
        { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/, loader: "file-loader"
        },
        {   test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"
          },
        {   test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader"
          }
      ]
    }

};
```

I could really use some assistance in the best way to use slick-carousel while building in NPM and with webpack. So many moving pieces and, when I kinda think I get it, this comes along and I spend 7 hours trying to fix it before asking for help.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, but I didn't want to change slick-carousel in my project, so one month late but here is how I solved it:

First install Webpack [image-loader](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader):

```
$ npm install image-webpack-loader --save-dev
```

Then change these lines (in your webpack configuration):

```
loaders: [{ 
          test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader", "file-loader")
        },
        {  
           test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
           loaders: [
            'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
           ]
        },
        { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
        { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader"
 }]
```

This will change file-loader (what you are using for loading images) for image-loader, it will know how to compile .gif files and other formats.

For aditional information about this, you can check the [github page](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader)

Also, if you are using [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/), don't use slick-carousel directly, because it uses direct DOM manipulation thanks to JQuery dependency, right now I'm using [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) is very stable and has cool options like **settings** based on **responsive layout** custom prev and next arrows and more.

I hope it help you

Answer (score 2):

```
require("slick-carousel/slick/slick.css");
require("slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css");
```

From what I understand you do not need both of these - only one.
Slick-theme is the default CSS, while Slick you integrate.

I could be wrong (I'm really new to development) but I've had no problems with the initial configuration!